# fastlane failing - undefined method `first'

Tags: fastlane

I was attempting to use fastlane today and I updated it to the newest version before I started (2.212.2).

When it gets to the step where it attempts to upload to the app store it fails with an error related to the "app_price" tiers. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
+------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
|                       fastlane summary                       |
+------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                                  | Time (in s) |
+------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                        | 0           |
| 2    | update_code_signing_settings            | 0           |
| 3    | update_project_team                     | 0           |
| 4    | match                                   | 13          |
| 5    | build_app                               | 27          |
| 6    | upload_app_privacy_details_to_app_store | 41          |
|    | upload_to_app_store                     | 15          |
+------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+

[16:23:51]: fastlane finished with errors

  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/deliver/lib/deliver/upload_price_tier.rb:24:in `upload': \e[31m[!] undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

      if app_prices.first
                   ^^^^^^\e[0m
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/deliver/lib/deliver/runner.rb:161:in `upload_metadata'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/deliver/lib/deliver/runner.rb:61:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/upload_to_app_store.rb:22:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:38:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:354:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in `take_off'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/gems/fastlane-2.212.2/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/bin/fastlane:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/fastlane/2.212.2/libexec/bin/fastlane:25:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating the app on App Store Connect, updating the price to $0 then commenting out the line `price_tier` in my `Deliverfile`. Then I was able to use fastlane to update everything else on the store listing & submit the app.

Reference the following PR & Issue for comments regarding this:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/21213

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/21236